# What is the relation of git and git-man?

Tags: 20.04, git

I Updated git to 1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.10 but git-man still on 1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.8.

Aren't they have dependency relationship?

I always think while I updated git, the git-man will update.

What is the relation of git and git-man?

Whether they need update respectively.

---The system I used is Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Thanks,I am a newer for Ubantu so is it the git depends on git-man not git-man depends on git? Then, they need update respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use apt tools to find out:

```
$ apt depends git | grep man
  Depends: git-man (>> 1:2.37.2)
  Depends: git-man (<< 1:2.37.2-.)
```

The `<<` and `>>` mean that `git` depends upon a *range* of versions of `git-man`.

The packages are not required to increment together, as long as the versions stay within the range. They often will increment together anyway, like during the build cycle of a new release. But it's not *required* that they do so.

Comment: Thanks! your words help me to understand my question.